# Update value based on value from nearest smaller neigbour

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column `A` that is INT(11) (it's a timestamp, but for now I just use small numbers)

```
id |  A | diff |
---+----+------+
 1 | 12 |      |
 2 |  7 |      |
 3 | 23 |      |
 4 |  9 |      |
 5 |  2 |      |
 6 | 30 |      |
```

I like to update `diff` with the difference between `A` and it's **nearest smaller neighbour**. So if `A=12` it's first smaller neightbour is `A=7`, if `A=30` it is `A=23`. I should end up with a table like this (sorted on A):

```
id |  A | diff |
---+----+------+
 5 |  2 |  -   |
 2 |  7 |  5   | (7-5)
 4 |  9 |  2   | (9-7)
 1 | 12 |  3   | (12-9)
 3 | 23 | 11   | (23-12)
 6 | 30 |  7   | (30-23)
```

I can calculate the difference at the moment of insertion, as I know `A` then (here: `A=15`):

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`A`,`diff`)
    (SELECT 15 , 15-`A` FROM `table` WHERE `A` < 15 ORDER BY `A` DESC LIMIT 1)
```

This results in a new record:

```
id |  A | diff |
---+----+------+
 7 | 15 |  3   |   (3 being the difference between A=12 and A=15
```

(**NOTE:** This fails miserably when `A=1`, being the new smallest value and having no smaller neighbour, so no value of `diff`)

But now the value of `diff` in record 3 is wrong, because it still is based on the difference between `23 - 12` as is now should be `23 - 15`.

So I just want to insert the `A` value and then run an update on the table, refreshing `diff` where necessery. But that's where my knowledge of MYSQL ends...

I crafted this query, but it fails saying `You can't specify table 't1' for update in FROM clause

```
UPDATE `table` AS t1
SET 
t1.`diff` = t1.`A` - (SELECT `A` FROM `table` 
                      WHERE `A` < t1.`A` 
                  ORDER BY `A` DESC LIMIT 1
                  )
```

Comment: Can you try my solution and let me know if it works ? Just trying to strengthen my concepts. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a query:

```
SELECT x.*
     , x.a-MAX(y.a) diff 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y  
    ON y.a < x.a 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id 
 ORDER 
    BY a;
```

I'm not sure why you would want to store derived data, but you can I guess...

```
UPDATE my_table m
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , x.a-MAX(y.a) q
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.a < x.a 
        GROUP 
           BY x.id
     ) n
    ON n.id = m.id 
   SET m.diff = q;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works (and I never would have come up with something like this myself).

Answer (score 0):

You may try this after inserting new value :

```
UPDATE x
SET
x.diff = iq2.new_diff 
FROM
#t x
 INNER JOIN
   (SELECt id,A,diff , new_diff 
     FROM
     (select id,A,15 as new_number, 
             CASE WHEN (A-15) < 0 THEN NULL ELSE (A-15) END as new_diff,diff 
      from #t
     ) iq
   WHERE 
   iq.new_diff <= iq.diff 
   AND iq.new_diff <> 0
  )iq2
on x.A = iq2.A
```

inner query compares the previous difference and current one and then updates the relevant ones.